# Microsoft Access will not process vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I began some code in VBA Access yesterday, but it would not run. I rebooted my computer and tried again and the code ran.

Today, same smell, but now after a restart, I still cannot get the code to process.

It is a code triggered by a textbox_change() event. As I said, yesterday the code worked, but today the event will not trigger.

Is this an Access setting that is not working or something getting turned on and off by accident?

I don't know too much aside from a bit of code to do what I need to. But if that code isn't being processed it does me no good.

Comment: When the textbox change code won't run, is there any other code in the db which will run?

Comment: No. I can't get it to display a message box or beep or anything. I've tried restarting both Access and the PC to no avail.

Comment: If your Access version is >= 2007, check whether this may be an issue with [trusted locations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-f5151879-25ea-4998-80a5-4208b3540a62)

Comment: That fixed it. You should add this as the answer so that I can give you some rep.

Comment: Hey, James.  I would prefer you submit the answer on this one, and then I can upvote you.  :-)  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you sir. I like this place. I think I'll stay, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to HansUp for aiding me on this fix. I was not aware of needing to save the file in a "Trusted Location" to enable VBA to run. Turns out when I would save the database, it was not in a "Trusted Location" so VBA was disabled.

If you go to Microsoft Access Options, Trust Center, Trust Center Settings, Trusted Locations, (That's a lot of trust, lol) - you can add your file save location to the list of "Trusted Locations".

Thanks again Hans.